# Which method for querying for the next set of posts in a user's social media feed do you prefer?

Tags: mysql, innodb, mariadb

Context:

- this if for an android app
- each user has a feed of posts -- think twitter
- my `user_feed` table is stored in a `MariaDB` database
- the table uses the `InnoDB`storage engine

`user_feed` table:

```
CREATE TABLE `user_feed` (
 `user_id` int(1) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `post_id` int(1) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `reposter_id` int(1) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
 `date_created` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
 PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`,`post_id`),
 KEY `user_id` (`user_id`),
 KEY `date_created` (`date_created`),
 KEY `post_id` (`post_id`),
 KEY `reposter_id` (`reposter_id`),
 CONSTRAINT `user_feed_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`post_id`) REFERENCES `post` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
 CONSTRAINT `user_feed_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `user` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Right now I use this SQL query to get a user's feed:

```
SELECT * FROM user_feed WHERE user_id = 29 ORDER BY date_created DESC LIMIT 40
```

I need a query for getting the next set of 40 posts from the `user_feed` table, but the problem is post 40 and post 41 may have been inserted at the same time, and the same could be true for posts 39, 42, etc.

Another problem is that I cannot use `LIMIT 41,80` because by the time the user needs the next 40 posts, there may have been more posts added to their feed, so the 40th post they received from the first query may not be the 40th post in the query result in additional attempts.

Methods for querying for the next set:

1. Have an unique auto_incrementing `index` column. So in order to query for the next forty posts I would use

   SELECT * FROM user_feed WHERE index < :post40Index LIMIT 40

The problem with this is that `index` would increment every time a post or repost was added to the `user_feed` table. That means every time a post is added to a user's feed, period. Even for 5000 users who are each only following 200 people this number seems like it would increment very quickly.

2. The same as above, but each user's feed would have their own increment column. I would have to keep track of this id myself. Whenever a post would be added to a particular user's feed, the highest index number for their feed would be grabbed, set for that post, and incremented so that the next post doesn't have the same index.

Problem with this is just that I feel like their is a simpler solution.

3. Pretty much the same as two, but I I keep track of the highest index for each user's feed in a list in memory instead of in a column in the `user` table.
4. Use:

   `SELECT * FROM user_feed WHERE date_created < :post40DateCreated LIMIT 40`
   And send the post ids of the posts that the user received from the first query that have the same date_created as post 40 with the GET request, and make sure the second query does not contain those posts ids -- add `post_id <> (post ids in request)` to the above query

Anybody think they got a better solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Both Insertions and Deletions can cause hiccups in what the user sees.  Plus, performance can be bad, even terrible, by using `OFFSET`.

Yes, "remember where you left off", and use that for the 'Next' button, not "page number".  Can there be duplicate values in `date_created`?

See my [*Pagination, not with OFFSET, LIMIT*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/pagination).